# Is it more correct to reuse a foreign key or create new ones?

Tags: database

Lets say you have the following table with fields:

SUPPLIERS:
Supplier ID (PK),
Supplier Status,
Supplier Country,

Suppose you want to capture a single project each company is working on from a defined list.

Is the most correct way to:

Create a new table called Supplier Project, with a copy of the Supplier ID field as a foreign key and another field called Project ID. This table would have a one-to-one relationship to the suppliers table on the Supplier ID field. Then create another table called Project with a copy of Project ID as its primary key and another field called Project Name. Seems like a one-to-many relationship with a join table though which seems to be weird.

Or should you create a separate foreign key in the Suppliers table to reference from? Or something else?

Seems like there are always lots of ways to approach these situations. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: _Hint 1_: do not create entities for entities. That is: if some entity is not needed to fulfill architecture, don't create it. _Hint 2_: FK is something that must refer to correct entity (so relationship with some parent entities) - thus, not sure if it "can be replaced" with some new key. Because if it can - then whole FK relationship is incorrect

Comment: Thanks for the hints. This wasn't a 'homework question' by the way. Just looking to gain a better understanding of designing databases :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on one hand you have an entity type called `Supplier` and, in the other, an entity type called `Project`, so a supplier could have zero or several associated projects.

That means, from the point of the entity-relationship model, a relationship between two entity types and this relationship is 0..n

This, translated to a relationship data model, means three tables:

- A table (`Supplier`) composed by the `SupplierID` (pk), `SupplierStatus` and `SupplierCountry`.
- A table (`Project`) composed by the `ProjectID` (pk) and other project-related
  fields.
- A table (`SupplierProject`) composed by the `SupplierID` and the `ProjectID`, inhereted as foreign and primary keys.

**Update:**

Now, as you stated that a supplier will work only in a project, that means a 1..1 relationship. In such cases you have three options:

- Create two tables with the own-related attributes of each entity type and import the PK from `Supplier` to `Project`. That means that a project must always have an associated supplier.
- Create two tables with the own-related attributes of each entity type and import the PK from `Project` to `Supplier`. That means that a supplier must always have an associated project. In case a supplier have not a project, and due a FK cannot be null, you could not represent such case.
- Create a single table with all the fields, in which you can make nullable the data related to the project to represent the situation in which a supplier have not an associated project. Anyway, in such cases it is better to adopt the first solution, in order to avoid tables with null values.

**Update 2:**

```
Case 1, in which each supplier always have one and only one associated project
```

The easiest approach is to create a single table with all the fields from `Supplier` and `Project`. The `ProjectID` field have not sense anymore.

```
Case 2, in which each supplier can have one and only one associated project
        (but also can have not associated projects)
```

You should create a table for the `Supplier` and other one for the `Project` entity types. The `Project` entity type will inherit the `SupplierID` as foreign and alternative key. That means that a project must ALWAYS have an associated supplier since AK cannot be null.

If you try to delete a certain supplier with an associated project, the DBMS will not permit you to do it.

This also means that a project associated to a given supplier must be deleted before you can assign a new project to this supplier because you cannot let the `SupplierID` inherited key in blank and neither repeat it in other row.

Comment: So the SupplierProject is a joining / linking table as in a many-to-many relationship. What if each supplier must have one, and only one, Project. Do you still build this many-to-many relationship model and enforce the constraint through the front end? Or how do you have a many-to-many set-up like this and enforce a compulsory one, and only one Project? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense and aligns with what I thought was going on. Still a little confused regarding how to enforce one and only one associated project to each supplier. Where you have such a case, do you still build a many-to-many relationship but as this encompasses the one-to-many situation just use it in this way? Sorry if this question doesn't make sense :)

Comment: Is it "one and only one" or "one, only one, and always one"?

Comment: Could you please provide an example for both cases? The one I am interested in is "one, only one, and always one" but am trying to learn as much as I can. Sorry - and this project can only be one of three from a predetermined list of projects.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for all the help! Just as an aside, I guess the downside of the solution to case one is if the name of a project changes, you would need to update every instance of this project name. Is it possible to then have an additional table which lists the project names so if any change, would only need to update in one spot. You have been super helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: No no no no ... If the name of a project changes, only change in one row. I am not considering in any case that a given project could be shared between two different suppliers.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. It seems I am causing a lot of trouble here :) What if the project can be shared between multiple companies? Does the original structure still hold? Understand if you have had enough of this one, as I didn't refine the question too well.

Comment: Well, it will be almost the same that having a supplier with several projects: you can 1) create two tables and inherit the `ProjectID` to the `Supplier` table or 2) create a third table with the `SupplierID` and the `ProjectID`.